# Sudo and backticks?

Tags: linux, bash, sudo

When running the following command:

```
sudo sh -c "sed s/sda1-uuid/`blkid -s UUID -o value /dev/sda1`/ -i /etc/crypttab"
```

the result is wrong, because `blkid -s UUID -o value /dev/sda1` is not executed with root privileges.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try single rather than double quotes.

Comment: Note that backticks are deprecated in favour of `$()`. (Although it has nothing to do with OP's problem.)

Comment: first store the output of `blkid -s UUID -o value /dev/sda1` to a variable and later substitute in the sed.

Comment: @user4440222 What is the error you are receiving?

Comment: I did not know that the dollar parens was prefered, but learned more here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126927/have-backticks-i-e-cmd-in-sh-shells-been-deprecated

Comment: This is a question about shell programming, and about when different parts of a command line are executed, and how to get them executed when desired.  As such, it is on topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

By trying the suggestions in the comments, the following command is now working as expected:

```
sudo sh -c 'sed s/sda1-uuid/$(blkid -s UUID -o value /dev/sda1)/ -i /etc/crypttab'
```